# Counting cumulative occurrences of values based on date window in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `DataFrame` (`df`) that looks like the following:

```
+----------+----+
| dd_mm_yy | id |
+----------+----+
| 01-03-17 | A  |
| 01-03-17 | B  |
| 01-03-17 | C  |
| 01-05-17 | B  |
| 01-05-17 | D  |
| 01-07-17 | A  |
| 01-07-17 | D  |
| 01-08-17 | C  |
| 01-09-17 | B  |
| 01-09-17 | B  |
+----------+----+
```

This the end result i would like to compute:

```
+----------+----+-----------+
| dd_mm_yy | id | cum_count |
+----------+----+-----------+
| 01-03-17 | A  |         1 |
| 01-03-17 | B  |         1 |
| 01-03-17 | C  |         1 |
| 01-05-17 | B  |         2 |
| 01-05-17 | D  |         1 |
| 01-07-17 | A  |         2 |
| 01-07-17 | D  |         2 |
| 01-08-17 | C  |         1 |
| 01-09-17 | B  |         2 |
| 01-09-17 | B  |         3 |
+----------+----+-----------+
```

### Logic

To calculate the cumulative occurrences of values in `id` but within a specified time window, for example `4 months`. i.e. every 5th month the counter resets to one.

To get the cumulative occurences we can use this `df.groupby('id').cumcount() + 1`

Focusing on `id = B` we see that the 2nd occurence of `B` is after 2 months so the `cum_count = 2`. The next occurence of `B` is at `01-09-17`, looking back 4 months we only find one other occurence so `cum_count = 2`, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My approach is to call a helper function from `df.groupby('id').transform`. I feel this is more complicated and slower than it could be, but it seems to work.

```
# test data

    date    id  cum_count_desired
2017-03-01  A   1
2017-03-01  B   1
2017-03-01  C   1
2017-05-01  B   2
2017-05-01  D   1
2017-07-01  A   2
2017-07-01  D   2
2017-08-01  C   1
2017-09-01  B   2
2017-09-01  B   3

# preprocessing

df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df.set_index('date', inplace=True)
# Encode the ID strings to numbers to have a column
# to work with after grouping by ID
df['id_code'] = pd.factorize(df['id'])[0]

# solution

def cumcounter(x):
    y = [x.loc[d - pd.DateOffset(months=4):d].count() for d in x.index]
    gr = x.groupby('date')
    adjust = gr.rank(method='first') - gr.size() 
    y += adjust
    return y

df['cum_count'] = df.groupby('id')['id_code'].transform(cumcounter)

# output

df[['id', 'id_num', 'cum_count_desired', 'cum_count']]

           id  id_num  cum_count_desired  cum_count
date                                               
2017-03-01  A       0                  1          1
2017-03-01  B       1                  1          1
2017-03-01  C       2                  1          1
2017-05-01  B       1                  2          2
2017-05-01  D       3                  1          1
2017-07-01  A       0                  2          2
2017-07-01  D       3                  2          2
2017-08-01  C       2                  1          1
2017-09-01  B       1                  2          2
2017-09-01  B       1                  3          3
```

#### The need for `adjust`

If the same ID occurs multiple times on the same day, the slicing approach that I use will overcount each of the same-day IDs, because the date-based slice immediately grabs all of the same-day values when the list comprehension encounters the date on which multiple IDs show up. Fix:

1. Group the current DataFrame by date.
2. Rank each row in each date group.
3. Subtract from these ranks the total number of rows in each date group. This produces a date-indexed Series of ascending negative integers, ending at 0.
4. Add these non-positive integer adjustments to `y`.

This only affects one row in the given test data -- the second-last row, because `B` appears twice on the same day.

#### Including or excluding the left endpoint of the time interval

To count rows *as old as or newer than* 4 calendar months ago, i.e., to *include* the left endpoint of the 4-month time interval, leave this line unchanged:

```
y = [x.loc[d - pd.DateOffset(months=4):d].count() for d in x.index]
```

To count rows *strictly newer than* 4 calendar months ago, i.e., to *exclude* the left endpoint of the 4-month time interval, use this instead:

```
y = [d.loc[d - pd.DateOffset(months=4, days=-1):d].count() for d in x.index]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can extend the groupby with a grouper:

```
df['cum_count'] = df.groupby(['id', pd.Grouper(freq='4M', key='date')]).cumcount()

Out[48]: 
        date id  cum_count
0 2017-03-01  A          0
1 2017-03-01  B          0
2 2017-03-01  C          0
3 2017-05-01  B          0
4 2017-05-01  D          0
5 2017-07-01  A          0
6 2017-07-01  D          1
7 2017-08-01  C          0
8 2017-09-01  B          0
9 2017-09-01  B          1
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to match the desired output. It looks like the right approach, but I'm not sure how to fix it.

Comment: If the id where distinct by date this would have been it. Thanks for this.

Answer (score 1):

We can make use of .apply row-wise to work on sliced df as well. Sliced will be based on the use of relativedelta from dateutil.

```
def get_cum_sum (slice, row):
    if slice.shape[0] == 0:
        return 1
    return slice[slice['id'] == row.id].shape[0]

d={'dd_mm_yy':['01-03-17','01-03-17','01-03-17','01-05-17','01-05-17','01-07-17','01-07-17','01-08-17','01-09-17','01-09-17'],'id':['A','B','C','B','D','A','D','C','B','B']}
df=pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df['dd_mm_yy'] = pd.to_datetime(df['dd_mm_yy'], format='%d-%m-%y')

df['cum_sum'] = df.apply(lambda current_row: get_cum_sum(df[(df.index <= current_row.name) & (df.dd_mm_yy >= (current_row.dd_mm_yy - relativedelta(months=+4)))],current_row),axis=1)

>>> df
    dd_mm_yy id  cum_sum
0 2017-03-01  A        1
1 2017-03-01  B        1
2 2017-03-01  C        1
3 2017-05-01  B        2
4 2017-05-01  D        1
5 2017-07-01  A        2
6 2017-07-01  D        2
7 2017-08-01  C        1
8 2017-09-01  B        2
9 2017-09-01  B        3
```

Thinking if it is feasible to use .rolling but months are not a fixed period thus might not work.